# adding 2 BigDecimal values

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
class Point {

  BigDecimal x;
  BigDecimal y;

  Point(double px, double py) {
    x = new BigDecimal(px);
    y = new BigDecimal(py);
  }

  void addFiveToCoordinate(String what) {
    if (what.equals("x")) {
      BigDecimal z = new BigDecimal(5);
      x.add(z);
    }
  }

  void show() {
    System.out.print("\nx: " + getX() + "\ny: " + getY());
  }

  public BigDecimal getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public BigDecimal getY() {
    return y;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p = new Point(1.0, 1.0);
    p.addFiveToCoordinate("x");
    p.show();
  }
}
```

Ok, I would like to add 2 BigDecimal values. I'm using constructor with doubles(cause I think that it's possible - there is a option in documentation). If I use it in main class, I get this:

```
x: 1
y: 1
```

When I use System.out.print to show my z variable i get this:

```
z: 5
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

BigDecimal is immutable. Every operation returns a new instance containing the result of the operation:

```
 BigDecimal sum = x.add(y);
```

If you want x to change, you thus have to do

```
x = x.add(y);
```

Reading [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) really helps understanding how a class and its methods work.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps this is what you prefer:

```
BigDecimal z = new BigDecimal(5).add(x);
```

Every operation of `BigDecimal` returns a new `BigDecimal` but not change the current instance.