# BigDecimal += (add and assign) ...How to do this?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I can't seem to locate an 'add and assign' method in the BigDecimal class.

Is there a method for this?

In case you don't understand my question I'm trying to do this:

`a += b;`

but I'm trying to do it with BigDecimals

Comment: First google result for `java bigdecimal add` gave me [adding-2-bigdecimal-values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850441/adding-2-bigdecimal-values).

Comment: you can't use the regular `+-*/` operators for BigDecimals as they are not primitives. tbh it sucks, its probably my top 1 most hated thing about Java (even tho I love it)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is an `add` method in the `BigDecimal` class.

You would have to do - `a = a.add(b);`

Have a look at the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add%28java.math.BigDecimal%29).

Comment: Thank you that both answers my questions and shows me what I need to do. Silly me, can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you!

Comment: In case you want for details. BigDecimal is a class same as Integer. Now in Java there is a primitive type for Integer which is int. So for int you can do what you want to i.e. the +=, however for BigDecimal and Integer you cannot do.

Comment: no I understand I just assumed that someone would have written that operator as a method for the BigDecimal class similar to the way in C++ you can write methods for any class to use the +,-,*,/ and assignment operators. Based on the answers here I'm assuming that you cannot do that

Answer (score 10):

I guess you would like something like this:

```
BigDecimal bd = getNumber();
bd.addAndAssign(5);
```

`BigDecimal` is an **immutable** object, so **no**, you cannot do that.

You must use `add()` and equal it to itself, e.g. `a = a.add(b)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why `+=` can't be done. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [BigDecimal#add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) method .

```
a = a.add(b);
```

Since BigDecimal is **immutable** , you cannot expect `a.add(b)` to mutate `a` . You have to return the new `BigDecimal` object to the reference `a` . Hence `a=a.add(b)` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimals are objects.  the `+=` operator only works with primitives.

So I don't think you can do what you are trying to propose.

Comment: That's not true in java > 1.5 with autoboxing you can use with WrapperClass for example Integer Double..

Answer (score 0):

Nope - there is no equivalent mechanism

You just have to use the `add` method